# Cannot get a text value from a numeric cell "Poi"

Tags: java, apache-poi

Estou tentando consumir dados de uma planilha em excel, porém sempre da este erro, ja tentei formatar a planilha para texto e para numero e mesmo assim o erro persiste.

Como arruma isso?

Vi que uma pessoa resolveu usando isso `cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);` mas não sei onde devo encaixar este trecho em meu código.

```
WebElement searchbox = driver.findElement(By.name("j_username"));
    WebElement searchbox2 = driver.findElement(By.name("j_password"));         




    try {

          FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\paulo.xls")); 
          HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

          HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        for (int i=1; i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++){

                String j_username = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();
                String j_password = sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0).getStringCellValue();


                searchbox.sendKeys(j_username);
                searchbox2.sendKeys(j_password);


                searchbox.submit();       

                driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        }

          workbook.close();
          file.close();

         } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {
          fnfe.printStackTrace();
         } catch (IOException ioe) {
          ioe.printStackTrace();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está obtendo uma instância do tipo [`Cell`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html) em `sheet.getRow(i).getCell(0)`.

Ou seja:

```
Cell cell = sheet.getRow(linhaDaCelula).getCell(colunaDaCelula);
```

Células podem ser do tipo `CELL_TYPE_BLANK`, `CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN`, `CELL_TYPE_ERROR`, `CELL_TYPE_FORMULA`, `CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC` ou `CELL_TYPE_STRING`.

Você pode obter o tipo da célula com o método `getCellStyle()` e modificá-lo com o método `setCellType()`.

Conforme o tipo da sua célula você deve utilizar os métodos corretos para obter seu valor. São eles: `getDateCellValue()`, `getErrorCellValue()`, `getNumericCellValue()`, `getRichStringCellValue()` e `getStringCellValue()`.

---

Repare que seu código fonte está estranho... Por exemplo, você está lendo tanto o usuário quanto a senha da primeira coluna (`getCell(0)`) de cada linha da planilha... Algo que não faz muito sentido (significaria que usuários e senhas são iguais, se esse for o caso você não precisaria ler duas vezes).

Comment: Obrigado Anthony.